# return a reference to an array with templated size

Tags: c++

I am trying a function's return value to be to a reference to an array whose size is variable (i.e. templated). The code I have is:

```
const char *strarr[] = { "one", "two", "three" };

template <std::size_t T>
const char* (&GetArr())[T]
{
    return strarr;
}
```

The reason I want to do it this way: it would be convenient in my case to then use in a a loop such that:

```
for (const auto& s : GetArr()) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
```

but this wouldn't compile. the only way to use it is to specify the size in GetArr(); but I was wondering why it can't deduce the size by itself, as it would have if I passed a reference to this array as a parameter to a templated function, as in:

```
template <std::size_t T>
void PrintArray(const char* (&arr)[T])
{
    for (const auto& s : arr)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

which does work.

Comment: When the array is passed to the function then the size can be deduced from the parameter, what do you want to use to deduce the size when the function has no arguments?

Comment: Well, maybe you should declare and use `GetArr` exactly like `PrintArray`?

Comment: template arguments are not "deduced by itself". When you call `PrintArry` then `T` is deduced to be the size of the array you pass as parameter.

Comment: the question is somewhat unclear. You know that you do not need the function to be able to write `for (const auto& s : strarr) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }` ?

Comment: 463035818_is_not_a_number
well it is true that the function has no arguments, but there is still a T in the declaration which I was expected to be deduced from the "return strarr", as in - I was expecting it the fill out the blank of T by knowing what it is returning with strarr

Comment: I realize I can use the array directly in the for loop, but I use it in a function because I later want to use this as a getter function without giving the user direct access to the array (encapsulate it in a way)

Comment: Maybe you may like `decltype(auto) GetArr() { return (strarr); }`. Note that parentheses around `strarr` are essential!

Comment: If you are using C++11 or later, you can use `std::array` and `std::string`, rather than mucking around with pointers or references to raw arrays.

Comment: Use a `std::array` instead.  those are easy to pass and return by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no template argument deduction from `return` statements and `T` cannot be deduced from any function parameter/argument pair.

So you will have to specify the size manually, but that is not a problem, since you need to specify the array that is returned anyway, so that the only possible choice is

```
const char* (&GetArr())[std::size(strarr)]
{
    return strarr;
}
```

That said, there is *return type deduction* via type placeholders which you can make use of here easily:

```
auto& GetArr()
{
    return strarr;
}
```

Note that in both cases the function is not a function template. There aren't multiple different instantiations that would make sense for it. There is only one possible size that makes sense, one possible return type and one possible function body. Therefore `template <std::size_t T>` doesn't really make sense to begin with.

However, it is much simpler to just use `std::array` instead of built-in arrays. The former doesn't require you to take care of special language rules or weird declaration syntax as in the first example.

---

There is also no need to write `PrintArray` so restrictively. You can instead write

```
template <typename R>
void PrintRange(const R& r)
{
    for (const auto& s : r)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and now you have a function that will work with any range, whether built-in array, `std::array`, `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc.

Comment: I have a follow-up question regarding your first example with ```const char* (&GetArr())[std::size(strarr)]```, if we assume that the definition of strarr[] is in that same cpp file where you defined this function, but the declaration for that function is separated to a header file, how would you know to declare it properly with the std::size(strarr) part if strarr is not available to the header, but rather defined in the cpp file (alongside the definition of the function)?

Comment: @steep It doesn't make sense to declare the function in the header file but not have `strarr` declared there (with complete type) as well. How would a caller of the function in a different translation unit than where the definition is located be able to know the return type of the function otherwise?

Comment: that is true, I was just hoping I can somehow go around this. so you are saying that the proper solution -- if I choose to use an array as such, rather than std::array and the other suggestions provided -- is to define it in that same header, in global scope as static, or alternatively in an anonymous namespace?

Comment: @steep No, I am saying you need to _declare_ it with complete type in the header before the declaration of the function. You can define the array wherever you want, e.g. `extern const char *strarr[3];` in the header is enough.

Comment: so just to summarize: I specify an exact number of elements for the array in the header, whereas in the cpp file I would use const char *strarr[] = {"element1", ..., "elementN"}, and each time I want to add a new element in the cpp file I have to remember to also change that number inside [] in the header. seems a bit inconvenient but did I grasp this correctly?

Comment: @steep Yes, you need to have the number of elements in the header. The whole point of what you are trying to do here seems to be to allow users of the function to iterate over the array for which they must know the number of elements. If you hide that information in another translation unit it can't work.

Comment: @steep Or simply use `std::vector` and have all of that be resolved at runtime.

Comment: @steep On the other hand if this is just a compile-time constant there is no problem in defining the array `const char * const strarr[] = { "one", "two", "three" };` or `constexpr const char * strarr[] = { "one", "two", "three" };` or `constexpr std::array strarr = { "one", "two", "three" };` in the header. The `const`/`constexpr` implies `static` for global (non-template non-inline non-`extern`) variables.